# How to configure google tagmanger for my app?

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

Can anyone provide a basic sample for configuring google tag manager in web interface and integrating gtm in android app.

Comment: Why do you want to use GTM inside an app? There are multiple SDKs out there to help with tracking in-app events, one of which is Google-owned Firebase.

Comment: yeah but using GTM we can dynamically manage tags.I have followed the above link but there is no clear description on how to configure tags and trigger them

Comment: Ah I understand. You could try this solution, that works with Firebase => https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/